# Window object in angular 5 service

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have project in Angular, user's panel in specific. All page is in php, just panel in angular. How to use `window` object in service?

I want use `window.location` exactly for the same action as href="/" in HTML, which return me to outside the angular project(panel) to main site. Why? When I was trying get user and it returns status for example 401, 404 user can not get access to panel, and it must navigate to main site.

I tried several options with route `navigate` or `navigateByURl`, but address was always set to baseHref in Angular, so I could not go outside. I tried pass `{provide: Window, useValue: window }` in providers, inject window to the constructor in service and this is working on my localhost, but when I run `ng build` in cli it sends mi a error:

> ERROR in Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UserService in
>   ../my-app/src/app/user.service.ts: (?, [object Object], [object
>   Object], [object Object], [object Object]).

Anyone please?

In AppModule:

```
providers: [UserService, DatePipe, {provide: Window, useValue: window }],
```

in UserSerice:

```
constructor(private window: Window, private location: Location, private HttpClient: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router){};
```

and function in UserService to navigate on status:

```
if(data == 403) {
  this.setError('You must log in', 'danger');

  this.window.location.assign("/");
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code

Comment: in edit. i can't show all code

Comment: try `window.location.assign("/");` without this. To access window you dont have to use this. I also believe its not necessary to import/provide window.

Comment: I reinstalled my npm packages(found similar problem), then I removed 'this' and import/provide and it works! Thank you!

Comment: If you remove this.window & the injection your just will disable the whoel DI for window: so of course it will work, but will be hard to test e.g. This defeats the wohloe idea behind DependencyInjection.

Answer (score 1):

```
ERROR in Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UserService in ../my-
app/src/app/user.service.ts: (?, [object Object], [object Object], 
[object Object], [object Object]).
```

This error occurs because angular is trying to inject Window and Location into your service and can't find corresponding classes with `@Injectable` decorator. The `@Injectable` decorator indicates that the Angular DI system is used to create one or more instances of the class. Also `window`  is a globally accessible object.

So instead of `this.window.location.assign("/");` you could use  `window.location.assign("/");`

Or any of this:

1. `window.location.href = 'http://...';`
2. `window.location = 'http://...';`