# Angular form, how to scroll to top automatically after successful submission of form?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-forms

I could not find a workable solution for my angular form. Basically I wish to scroll back to the top automatically after my form is being captured successfully.

I am able to capture the submission and reset the form but is having some difficulty in trying to scroll back to the top automatically after form reset.

This is my `onSubmit()` function in my `account-payable.component.ts`:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.accountPayableForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.accountPayableService
      .submitAccountPayable(this.accountPayableForm.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.alertService.success(
            'Success! Account payable created with reference ID: ' +
              data.valueOf(),
            true
          );
          this.loading = false;
          this.submitted = false;
          this.accountPayableForm.reset();
          this.goToTop();
        },
        error => {
          this.alertService.error(error);
          this.loading = false;
        }
      );
  }
```

My `goToTop()` function doesn't seems to be working:

```
goToTop() {
    window.scroll({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }
```

I have tried to replace `this.goToTop();` with `window.scrollTo(0,0);` but it's not working as well, my form still stays at the bottom and my success message is displayed above the form and I'll have to manually scroll up to check after submission.

Any advise? Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find any issues with the code. Could you create a stackblits demo and share the link if you can recreate the same?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: using angular 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
document.querySelector("main").scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Where you replace "main" with whatever element that you have wrapped around `<router-outlet>`.

You couldn't use window because it's likely you have nested your `<router-outlet>` inside another element. In my program for example, I have wrapped a `<main>` element around `<router-outlet>`:

[image]

hence, I have to *select* `<main>` element and target it to scroll to top.

I don't know how your app is structured and I think it is a waste of time to ask you to post the structure of app. Examine your dev tools' *Elements* tab (Chrome) or *Inspector* tab (firefox) and **target the correct element that has a defined height** (which allowed scrolling to happen; Note: it may not even be an element that wraps around router-outlet!). You should be able to scroll to top then.

You can actually test `document.querySelector("main").scrollTo(0, 0);` in the browser's console to see if you're targetting the correct element and the scroll is working (ignore the *undefined* response):

[image]

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much! May I ask if this "because it's likely you have nested your <router-outlet> inside another element" is bad? Is this a bad way to structure my app?

Comment: I shouldn't think so, I have done it to apply CSS on routed components that are rendered in `<router-outlet>` because I couldn't apply CSS directly to `<router-outlet>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to scroll to top, use this:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Comment: actually I have tried this but it's not working for me. I replaced ```this.goToTop();``` with ```window.scrollTo(0,0);``` but my form still stays at the bottom where my success message is displayed above the form and I have to scroll back up each time  to see the message if I submit form continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.

window.scroll(0,0);

Check this link

[Window object in angular 5 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004605/window-object-in-angular-5-service)

This would help in proper declaration and use of the window object

Comment: It seems that window is not recognised by the angular can u debug it and check the function

Comment: Open the developer console in the browser and directly type the above code if it works then window has to be defined in angular as any

Comment: it says "undefined" when I keyed in the function ```window.scroll(0,0);```

Comment: Check the link in the answer

Comment: Have gone through the link but I'm still unsure of how I can change ```window.scroll(0,0);```? There isn't any assign function for scroll that I can define like the case in the link you've provided. Do I have to import Window in my AppModule?

Comment: {provide: Window, useValue: window} add this providers